# SQL Server INNER JOIN on 2 same tables

Tags: sql-server

Table-1

```
START   END rownum
1   1   1
2   3   2
4   7   3
8   8   4
9   9   5
```

Table-2

```
START   END rownum
1   1   1
2   3   2
4   7   3
8   8   4
9   9   5
```

Query:

```
SELECT TB1.START,TB1.[END],TB1.rownum as row_1,TB2.START,TB2.[END],TB2.rownum as row_2 FROM 
(
select START,[END],ROW_NUMBER() over(order by import_num) as rownum from 
table1 
) TB1
INNER JOIN
(
select START,[END],ROW_NUMBER() over(order by import_num) as rownum from 
table1 
) TB2
ON TB1.rownum + 1 = TB2.rownum
```

Result:

```
START   END row_1   START   END row_2
1   1   1   2   3   2
2   3   2   4   7   3
4   7   3   8   8   4
8   8   4   9   9   5
```

Question:

Why would the rownum will indicate-1,2,3,4 when my join condition is on tb1.rownum + 1?
Shouldn't it be 2,3,4,5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're `JOIN`ing on rownum + 1, but not `SELECT`ing it...

Change:

```
SELECT TB1.START,TB1.[END],TB1.rownum as row_1
    ,TB2.START,TB2.[END],TB2.rownum as row_2 FROM ....
```

To:

```
SELECT TB1.START,TB1.[END],(TB1.rownum + 1) as row_1
    ,TB2.START,TB2.[END],TB2.rownum as row_2 FROM ....
```

Answer (score 1):

Your output seems fine to me. I don't know the best way to display this, but here's one way to visualize what is joining to what:

```
Table1.RowNum   +1      Table2.RowNum
1               2       2
2               3       3
3               4       4
4               5       5
5               6       null    /* no 6 in Table2.RowNum */
null            null    1       /* no 0 in Table1.RowNum */
```

In the last two rows here, see how there is no 6 in Table2.RowNum?  Also, you can't add 1 to any Table1.RowNum and match Table2.RowNum = 1

Also, I'm not sure of the source of `import_num` in your query since you're not showing us that in your table definitions. This is a potential source of confusion in my mind.

Comment: Its correct..I was somehow confused expecting tb1 + 1 values while selecting tb1.start & tb1.end...THanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this adding 1 to rownum while row_number, this will Join on 2,3,4,5.

```
SELECT TB1.START,TB1.[END],TB1.rownum as row_1,TB2.START,TB2.[END],TB2.rownum as row_2 FROM 
(
select START,[END],ROW_NUMBER() over(order by import_num) + 1 as rownum from 
table1 
) TB1
INNER JOIN
(
select START,[END],ROW_NUMBER() over(order by import_num) as rownum from 
table1 
) TB2
ON TB1.rownum  = TB2.rownum
```